# How to create barplot with facet and add labels with seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have the following `dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'reg' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'file': ['1', '1', '2'],
                   'val' : [1, 2, 3]})
```

I would like to create a `barplot` using `seaborn`, with `faceting` by `file`, color by `reg` and also add the `val` on top of each bar

I have tried this

```
  import seaborn as sns
  g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='file', hue='reg', col_wrap=2)
  g.map(sns.barplot, 'reg', 'val').add_legend()
  g.savefig('test_so.png')
```

But, this doesn't do the coloring right

Any ideas?

Comment: You should see a warning saying `UserWarning: Using the barplot function without specifying *order* is likely to produce an incorrect plot.` So usually it's a good idea to do what warnings say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `order` parameter, add `unique` per @jdehesa mentions below:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='file', hue='reg', col_wrap=2)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'reg', 'val', order=df.reg.unique()).add_legend()
```

Output:

[image]

---

### Add labels to bars in facetgrid plot

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='file', hue='reg', col_wrap=2)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'reg', 'val', order=df.reg.unique()).add_legend()

for ax in g.axes:
    for p in ax.patches:
             ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 5),
                 textcoords='offset points')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: why is the order "mandatory" in this case ? Mandatory in the sense, that you lose data if you dont use it

Comment: No, you are not losing data, I think if you don't put "order", you are plotting B on top of A.   Yes, if add some alpha, you'll see A beneath B without order.

Comment: Thank you for that. Any ideas for the labels ?

Comment: I don't understand your question about labels.

Comment: What I mean is: on top of each bar, have the `val`. So in your plot above the blue bar show "1", above the orange bar show "2" etc

Comment: I get `'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'patches'`

Comment: You are going to have to access each axes in that facet grid and apply that logic.

Comment: I do not know how to do that